# Getting the error java.lang.NullPointerException when running application through spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-ml

**Exception**

```
2020-10-31 18:00:40,904 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getName(Path.java:414)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$8(SparkSubmit.scala:376)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:376)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**My build.sbt file**

```
    name := "StockPredictionStructuredStreaming"
    version := "0.1"
    scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.0.0"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "3.0.0"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "3.0.0"
```

Comment: My spark submit command -spark-submit --class SparkStructuredStreaming.StockPredictionKafkaStructuredStreaming --jars /home/niraj/IdeaProjects/StockPredictionStructuredStreaming/target/scala-2.12/stockpredictionstructuredstreaming_2.12-0.1.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0,org.apache.spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.0 "localhost:9092" "kafkatutorial" "./SavedOutput" "./pythonFiles/StockPricePrediction.py"

Comment: Post complete code ??

Comment: My code is working fine while using intellij...facing issue while using spark-submit only

Comment: issue inside your code, not with sbt file.. post code then only any one can help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
spark-submit --class SparkStructuredStreaming.StockPredictionKafkaStructuredStreaming --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0,org.apache.spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.0 /home/niraj/IdeaProjects/StockPredictionStructuredStreaming/target/scala-2.12/stockpredictionstructuredstreaming_2.12-0.1.jar "localhost:9092" "kafkatutorial" "./SavedOutput" "./pythonFiles/StockPricePrediction.py"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.